# Load data from database to dynamic created textarea

Tags: angularjs

I have 10 textarea that is generated dynamically, like user can add or remove the textarea. I am fetching some data from database and that is working fine but facing issue while displaying them.

Here is the code:

```
<fieldset  data-ng-repeat="choice in choices">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-10">
                <textarea name="{{choice.name}}" ng-model="choice.name" class="form-control textbox1" id="exp_details" placeholder="Experience" required="required" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <button class="remove" ng-show="$last" ng-click="removeChoice()">-</button>
            </div>

        </fieldset>
```

Here is the http request:

```
formApp.controller('getprofile', function($scope,$http){
    $http({
        url: 'get_profile.php',
        method: "GET",
        params: {uid: uid}
    })
    .success(function(data) {
        
        if (data.success) {
            
            // What can I do here?
            
        }else{
            alert('Error');
        }
    });
})
```

How can I fix this issue?

Data from http request is like this:

```
exp = 'some text';
exp1 = 'some text';
exp2 = 'some text';
--------------------
exp10 = 'some text';
```

### Edit

http://www.shanidkv.com/blog/angularjs-adding-form-fields-dynamically

I am using code from above link and trying to add existing value in textarea.

Comment: Your HTML is malformed. The `success` callback on the `$http` promise has been removed too

Comment: How does your `choices` array looks like? Is that populated from ajax call?

Comment: What **exactly** does the response data look like? Why does it have a `success` property?

Answer (score 0):

If your `choices` and `data` are array with objects something like this,

```
 $scope.choices = [
    { id: 1, name: ""},
    { id: 2, name: ""},
    { id: 3, name: ""},
    { id: 4, name: ""}
  ]

  $scope.data = [
    { exp0: " 1 text for choice 1"},
    { exp1: " 2 text for choice 2"},
    { exp2: " 3 text for choice 3"},
    { exp3: " 4 text for choice 4"},
  ]
```

Then your solution can be,

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope,$http) {
  $scope.choices = [
    { id: 1, name: ""},
    { id: 2, name: ""},
    { id: 3, name: ""},
    { id: 4, name: ""}
  ]
  
  // this code come in success method
  
  $scope.data = [
    { exp0: " 1 text for choice 1"},
    { exp1: " 2 text for choice 2"},
    { exp2: " 3 text for choice 3"},
    { exp3: " 4 text for choice 4"},
  ]
  
  $scope.data.forEach(function (value, i) {
    $scope.choices[i].name =  value['exp'+i]
    console.log(i.toString());
    console.log($scope.choices[i].name)
  });
  
  // this code come in success method
  
  
  
  $http({
        url: 'get_profile.php',
        method: "GET",
        params: {uid: 'uid'}
    })
    .success(function(data) {

        if (data.success) {

            // above code comes here


        }else{
            alert('Error');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<fieldset  data-ng-repeat="choice in choices">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-10">
                <textarea name="{{choice.name}}" ng-model="choice.name" class="form-control textbox1" id="exp_details" placeholder="Experience" required="required" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>
            <!--<div class="col-xs-2">
                <button class="remove" ng-show="$last" ng-click="removeChoice()">-</button>
            </div>-->

</fieldset>



</body>
</html>
```

**Please run the above snippet.**

[**HERE IS THE WORKING DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/PHwiBNRHGrKgH3JZKqWJ?p=preview)